# Excel VBA - How to use worksheet event in add-in module?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel Add-ins and I am not sure how to write mi programm.
I would like to put in an add-in a code so that, when the workbook that uses the add-in is opened, it creates a sheet named "mainSheet".

I can use the event handler in the Workbook, but is it possible to put the code in the module of the add-in and still be able to run it?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the "Automate Excel" web site. Hope this helps

The following code works opening a workbook. It automatically adds a new sheet and labels it with the name. It also checks to see that the sheet doesn’t already exist – to allow for the possibility of it being opened more than once a day.

This code makes use of the Workbook Open Event and **must** be placed in the **workbook** module under the “Open work Book” event. The function Sheet_Exists must be placed in a module and this checks whether or not the sheet exists:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim New_Sheet_Name As String

New_Sheet_Name = "mainSheet"

If Sheet_Exists(New_Sheet_Name) = False Then
   With Workbook
       Worksheets.Add().Name = New_Sheet_Name
   End With
End If

End Sub
```

==

```
Function Sheet_Exists(WorkSheet_Name As String) As Boolean

Dim Work_sheet As Worksheet

Sheet_Exists = False

For Each Work_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If Work_sheet.Name = WorkSheet_Name Then
        Sheet_Exists = True
     End If
Next

End Function
```